# xslt select matching value from nested loop

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, foreach, nested

I need help with this simple xslt looping.
Need All matching DocInstance loops selected for matching (Transetconnum2/Transetconnum = DocInstance/set_ctrl_nbr)
Below XML.

```
<Documents>
    <Transetconnum2>
        <Transetconnum>0001</Transetconnum>
        <Transetconnum>0003</Transetconnum>
    </Transetconnum2>
    <DocInstance>
        <doc_ref_id>9178191-RBTW</doc_ref_id>
        <set_ctrl_nbr>0001</set_ctrl_nbr>
        <grp_ctrl_nbr>206875</grp_ctrl_nbr>
        <int_ctrl_nbr>682651</int_ctrl_nbr>
    </DocInstance>
    <DocInstance>
        <doc_ref_id>9178192-RBTW</doc_ref_id>
        <set_ctrl_nbr>0002</set_ctrl_nbr>
        <grp_ctrl_nbr>206875</grp_ctrl_nbr>
        <int_ctrl_nbr>682651</int_ctrl_nbr>
    </DocInstance>
    <DocInstance>
        <doc_ref_id>9178193-RBTW</doc_ref_id>
        <set_ctrl_nbr>0003</set_ctrl_nbr>
        <grp_ctrl_nbr>206875</grp_ctrl_nbr>
        <int_ctrl_nbr>682651</int_ctrl_nbr>
    </DocInstance>
</Documents>
```

Expected output:

```
<Documents>
    <DocInstance>
        <doc_ref_id>9178191-RBTW</doc_ref_id>
        <set_ctrl_nbr>0001</set_ctrl_nbr>
        <grp_ctrl_nbr>206875</grp_ctrl_nbr>
        <int_ctrl_nbr>682651</int_ctrl_nbr>
    </DocInstance>
    <DocInstance>
        <doc_ref_id>9178193-RBTW</doc_ref_id>
        <set_ctrl_nbr>0003</set_ctrl_nbr>
        <grp_ctrl_nbr>206875</grp_ctrl_nbr>
        <int_ctrl_nbr>682651</int_ctrl_nbr>
    </DocInstance>
</Documents>
```

Comment: Why is `<set_ctrl_nbr>0002</set_ctrl_nbr>` excluded from your output?

Comment: As there is no match for Transetconnum>0002  against set_ctrl_nbr, 0002 is excluded.

Comment: apologies the input vs expected output was wrong earlier, ive editted it. Hope this is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for any looping here (and certainly not a "nested loop"). Simply copy the nodes that match the "allowed" values:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Documents">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="DocInstance[set_ctrl_nbr = ../Transetconnum2/Transetconnum]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For explanation, read the [comparison rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans) as defined in the XPath specification:

> If both objects to be compared are node-sets, then the comparison will
> be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a
> node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the
> comparison on the string-values of the two nodes is true.